# error " svn:SSLv3 SSLContext not available on RAD 7.5

Tags: java, svn, request, sslv3, sslcontext

I am getting the error " SVN: SSLv3 SSLContext not available    SVN: OPTIONS request failed on ('SVN URL') while trying to connect to SVN repository through RAD 7.5.
I am using web sphere 7.0. 
I am able to remote desktop to the server and also can login using the URL directly. 
Only problem is through RAD.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that RAD 7.5 does not support modern TLS/SSL versions, and supports only SSL 3.0 or older. I think that your server does not enable SSL 3.0 for security reasons. SSL 3.0 is deprecated and not secure.

Comment: RAD comes with an embedded JDK older version and It doesn't support TLS.